# Set color for UI window border on Blender 2.83

Tags: interface

i found it.Preferences > Themes > User Interface> Styles> Editor Outline[image]

Comment: Hello :). Probably buried somewhere in *Preferences > Themes > User Interface*. It's not that long a list...

Comment: thanks, i found it; Preferences > Themes > User Interface> Styles> Editor Outline